# Will restarting a mission affect my rank?

Tags: metal-gear-solid-5-the-phantom-pain

Like the title says I'm wondering if I get a clean slate if I restart a mission.

**Here's a scenario:** I've been trying a mission over and over from checkpoint, triggering alarms and whatnot. This will obviously affect my rank since it will deduct a lot of points.

I don't want this (who would?). Now, once again for the question: **Will I get a complete do-over if I restart the mission?** Granting me the ability to get that long awaited *S-rank* instead of that lousy *D-rank*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it will. The "restart mission" is exactly what it implies, even though it might not be so obvious at first (it sure as hell was not for me).

Originally I personally thought that restarting the mission was intended for re-watching cinematics and starting over, with your current actions still intact.

Personally this makes me love the game even more since now I can start over if I feel that my performance was lacking and knew I could do better.

**TL;DR** : Yes! Don't settle for that ***E-rank*** when you can get an ***S-rank***!

Comment: Keep in mind that the only thing that really effects your RANK is your SCORE. Restarting a mission effects your SCORE, but you might still get S-rank. You need 130,000 points for S-rank, so simply restarting is not enough to lose out on S-Rank if you then complete the mission with top marks. Restarting allows you to undo all the actions of the current mission with the exception of items that made it back to mother base.

Comment: I knew you could improve your rank by replaying a mission (I haven't encountered a single game where that isn't possible), but can you actually end up with a worse score?